# ASP.NET MVC send email attachment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stream, email-attachments

I have a controller action which generates and streams a PDF to the client, but would also like to have a controller action which emails the output of that PDF download action as an attachment.  I know how to send an email, the question is how can I use/capture that MVC download action for my email attachment.

Pseudo code:

```
public PdfResult Download(int? someId)
{
     var pdfBuilder = new pdfBuilder();
     var pdfStream = pdfBuilder.StreamPdf(someId);
     return new PdfResult("someId.pdf", "application/pdf", pdfStream);
}

public ActionResult Email(int? someId)
{
     var pdfStream = View("Download", someId);
     var attachment = new Attachment(pdfStream, "someId.pdf");

     //...send email code
}
```

Comment: If you do already have that `PdfBuilder` of yours, why don't you just call it again when sending the email...? And if you don't want to duplicate code, just refactor the pdf generation code into a third method.

Comment: What are you using for sending email and what does it need for an attachment. That is does it require a physical file or a filestream?

Comment: Just SmptClient, typical .Net send email mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to add a helper class to return the PdfResult instead of calling Download() in your Email() method.

Comment: I like to be able to just use the same output of that download action since it already is binary.

Comment: You would call the helper from both methods. That would better adhere to the MVC pattern. You would receive the same output for both calls.